# Is there a way to get the stories that are trending from the facebook api?

Tags: javascript, facebook, web

In there a way to get the stories that are trending on facebook, like the ones that show up in the top right corner?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get facebook trending relative to country?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585573/how-to-get-facebook-trending-relative-to-country)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no API for getting those stories.

The answer that Raúl refers to mentions the [Keyword Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/keyword_insights). This is a pretty restricted functionality, but you would be able to work with one of the partners listed there.