# Is it possible to access the Facebook currently trending topics?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm wondering if I'm able to access this list of trending topics possibly using the FBSDK to display this information within my iOS app.

Comment: Looking at the page pointed to [by this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585573/how-to-get-facebook-trending-relative-to-country), it appears that the API is still not publicly available.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not exposed via the current Public Graph API version.